# Is LaTeX suitable for documents that need to be edited a lot?

Tags: pdf, editors

I'm looking for a document format that will be suitable for a large number of notes that I take.

I'm mostly concerned with:

- Future proof (so that I can always access my notes even if I switch operating systems or word processors)
- Embedding (ability to embed images, tables, code blocks, math equations etc.)
- Relatively easy to access and edit (counter example would be PDF)

Would LaTeX be a good candidate? 

 From what I understand .tex files aren't the best when it comes to reading straight from them, but can you compile the .tex file to something other than PDF?

How hard would it be to maintain a database full of LaTeX files?

Comment: You might try asking the people behind [Authorea](http://www.authorea.com) - it's a website for collaborative writing of scientific papers, and commenting on them, and it's based on LaTeX, so they should have useful feedback on this topic.

Comment: Because `tex` documents are in plain text, the edit trail (revision control) is very easy to produce and maintain using standard tools (variants of `diff`, for example).  Portability across platforms is unparalleled, I would think.

Comment: Welcome! Why do you want to compile to something other than PDF? I mean, yes, you can, but I don't see why you'd want to. As mentioned above, plain text is about as future-proof, portable and easily accessible/editable as it gets, is very, very, very easy to combine with version control (I use subversion, but git is another popular choice) and is easy to maintain. `.tex` files are plain text. LaTeX or ConTeXt make it easy to embed images, create tables, format code listings etc. Support for typesetting maths is, of course, unparalleled even now.

Comment: Word processors are irrelevant, though. You don't want to use a word processor for editing `.tex` files. You can easily switch IDE/editor. At a pinch, you can also use any genuinely plain text editor even if it has no special support for LaTeX. What you compile the `.tex` to is irrelevant for your purposes because you don't need to alter to output. To edit, you edit the `.tex` file and recompile.

Comment: Embedding, as you seem to mean it, will be a drawback. You can't drag-n-drop an image or table into the raw `.tex` file, though you can certainly include images for the PDF output, and TeX can certainly do tables.

Comment: These comments are useful, thanks a lot. Is there a way to edit the .tex documents without looking at the source code? (maybe by hiding the tags in an editor)

Comment: @dcweaver01 There is LyX, or as already noted online 'front end' services such as Overleaf, ShareLaTeX and Authorea.

Comment: Great, I'm on Ubuntu so I'll check out LyX and TeXmaker

Comment: @dcweaver01 Have a look at orgmode: http://orgmode.org/ , you can export to LaTeX as well as html and many other formats. Besides that, it is always a good idea to learn LaTeX.

Comment: @KeksDose In orgmode, do you actually have to write the LaTeX source code with your text or does it convert the org file to LaTeX automatically?

Comment: Org converts things for you (based on various parameters you set if you want to go beyond the defaults). Simple documents may be written in markdown or org-mode and converted to *TeX with profit; more complex documents should simply and directly be written in your format of TeX. Otherwise, you'd need to add a layer of complexity via something like [GPP](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html). And, in fact, known the target 'language' (e.g., LaTeX) will help you write the source 'language' ... so I'd say learn *TeX first regardless.

Comment: @jon Some editors will automatically add the code if you drag and drop an image to the source window. (TeXShop does this, I think. I assume it isn't unique.)

Comment: If what you really want to ask is whether LaTeX is suitable for you, given that you don't want to learn LaTeX, then, no, LaTeX is not suitable in that case. Even if you plan to use LyX or an online service, you will need LaTeX for the difficult bits and will have far fewer problems if you understand the code also for the easy bits.

Comment: @cfr -- That is fairly remarkable. Though I suppose you'd often need to 'fix' or tweak the code the drag-n-drop creates.

Comment: @jon I never liked it, to be honest. It is easier to just use auto-completion. But it is useful with complex paths as it gets the path correct automatically. It is probably - I'm guessing here - hooking into a facility provided by Cocoa. I can't really think otherwise that it would have been worth the effort required to programme it. (But I know very little about programming in general or TeXShop's code in particular.)