# Can embedding objects into a document be done in LaTeX?

Tags: embedding

Is it possible to create a document with embedded objects like so?

[image]

Comment: The `media9` package allows to embed video or sound files. Images are no problem with `graphicx`.  As to ‘block of code’, I'm unsure of what you mean, but I suppose `listings`  should do it.

Comment: Is this significantly different from your earlier question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330505/is-latex-suitable-for-documents-that-need-to-be-edited-a-lot ?

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the answers [in this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/8528) to get an idea of what can be done in LaTeX. The [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Manuals) are also usually quite interesting.

Comment: @Bernard This is what I wanted to know, If you post it as an answer I'll choose it. @_cfr I believe so. @_jon This is interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `media9` package allows to embed video or sound files. `Beamer` also has a `multimedia` package, which allows for inclusion of animations or sound files.

Images are no problem with `graphicx`. Supported formats are  `.eps` for LaTeX, `.pdf`, `.png` and `.jpg` for pdfLaTeX. The `svg` package allows further to include `.svg` images.

As to ‘blocks of code’, it can be done through the `listings` package.

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifically looking for code to help get you started, there are some short examples on Overleaf (full disclosure - I'm one of the founders) which show you how you can set this up for e.g. `media9`:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-media9-to-include-videos-files/yvdwwvpknjkk

and `listings`:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/syntax-highlighting-in-latex-with-the-listings-package/jxnppmxxvsvk#.WFewC_mLReU

For positioning the embedded items with wrapped text, you might also want to check out the `wrapfig` package:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/package-example-wrapfig/hmdrphhbxmjp